# CodeIgniter4 Shield, How to customize validation message of login and registration?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I just added codeigniter 4 custom shield package to my project for login and registration. I'm able to change the valdiation rules using Validation.php file in the app Config folder. but i dont have any idea where to change the valdiation message ?

How i can change validation message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI Shield's Validation messages are created from [language files](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/localization.html).

You need to copy the `vendor/codeigniter4/shield/src/Language/en/Auth.php` to `app/Language/en/Auth.php` and then you can edit the validation messages (and all other message-strings) there.

If it's not there, it's probably a CI4 core message and you need to overwrite those language files (same procedure, different path as above).

**Edit:**
To change the error message for validation errors add this to your rules array in `Config\Validation.php`:

```php
'email' => [
   'label'  => 'Email',
   'rules'  => 'required|valid_email|unique_email[{id}]',
   'errors' => [
      // This determines the error message for the "unique_email" validation rule:
      'unique_email' => 'This email is already in use. Could belong to a current or a deleted user.',
   ],
],
```

Comment: Yes that's fine. but what i need to do is, i want to change the validation message if someone not enter a valid email

Comment: I don't know if i get this right. Do you mean the message like `Unable to verify the email address matches the email on record.`? Because that is in the above mentioned `Auth.php`-file.

Comment: Or do you mean something like this: `'email' => [ 'label'  => 'Email', 'rules'  => 'required|valid_email|unique_email[{id}]', 'errors' => ['unique_email' => 'This email is already in use. Could belong to a current or a deleted user.', ], ],`?